# How to evaluate a promise of an Angular app remotely via chrome-remote-interface

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, google-chrome-devtools, zonejs

I'm using the chrome-remote-interface node package to access an Angular app remotely. 
To evalate an expression that returns a Promise, I use this code snippet:

```
Runtime.evaluate({expression, awaitPromise: true, returnByValue: true});
```

I get the follwing error message:

```
Error: Result of the evaluation is not a promise
```

I'm aware, that zone.js is monkey-patching the Promise with a ZoneAwarePromise.
Could that be the reason, or am I doing something wrong? Is there a way to use the native Promise?

Comment: I just tried it with ```NativePromise.resolve(my ZoneAwarePromise)``` (stored it at the window object in zone.js source). Then it worked! Strange thing is, that it works flawlessly on my local machine if I use a Chrome instance with remote-debugging. On my remote machine, Chrome 60 is used. Was that an issue with older Chrome versions?

Comment: Just found out that I can get the original native promise via ```window.__zone_symbol__Promise```. So I have a workaround now. But the question still is: Why does it work with my local Chrome, but not with the remote Chrome 60?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, that chrome-remote-interface could not evaluate the ZoneAwarePromise which replaces the native Promise when using zone.js. zone.js stores the original native Promise in window.__zone_symbol__Promise.

Using `Runtime.evaluate({window.__zone_symbol__Promise.resolve(expression), awaitPromise: true, returnByValue: true});` fixed it for me. It's really just a workaround, though, depending on zone.js implementation details and thus should not be used in production code.